# Trying to take certain rows from a dataframe with a certain criteria

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataset trying to do some MLR on variables, and I want to make 2 different models by splitting the original dataset into 2 different genders.

The dataset and models is as follows:

```
library(carData)
num_mod <- data.frame(as.numeric(Salaries$rank), as.numeric(Salaries$discipline), 
                            Salaries$yrs.since.phd, Salaries$yrs.service, 
                            as.numeric(Salaries$sex))
```

Does anyone know how I could split this data frame from the as.numeric(Salaries$sex) portion to make a model for females - 1, and males - 2?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(tidyverse)
library(carData)

## name your variables 

num_mod <- data.frame(salary_rank = as.numeric(Salaries$rank),
                      discipline = as.numeric(Salaries$discipline), 
                      years_since_phd = Salaries$yrs.since.phd,
                      years_service = Salaries$yrs.service, 
                      sex = as.numeric(Salaries$sex))




### turn create a binary variable called female and remove sex

num_mod2 <- 
num_mod %>% mutate( female = as.numeric(sex == 1)) %>%  select(-sex)


## a simple logistic model 
my_logit_model <- 
glm(female ~ ., data = num_mod2, family = "binomial")
```

resulting model

```
summary(my_logit_model)
   
# Call:
#   glm(formula = female ~ ., family = "binomial", data = num_mod2)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#   Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
# -0.7029  -0.5201  -0.3977  -0.3044   2.5058  

# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)     -0.91285    0.75321  -1.212    0.226
# salary_rank     -0.14521    0.30859  -0.471    0.638
# discipline      -0.20862    0.35209  -0.593    0.554
# years_since_phd -0.00280    0.03810  -0.073    0.941
# years_service   -0.03969    0.03460  -1.147    0.251
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
# Null deviance: 255.03  on 396  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 243.70  on 392  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 253.7
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Comment: My only question is what would 


`num_mod %>% mutate( female = as.numeric(sex == 1)) %>%  select(-sex)`

look like if it didn't have the chaining `%>%` part

Comment: it would be something like (didn't check the syntax)  
num_mod$female <- as.numeric(num_mod$sex == 1)
num_mod2$sex <- NULL

Comment: I'm getting an error becasue the replacement has 0 rows, but the data has 397. Sorry to ask so many questions in one post, I'm still learning.

Comment: try num_mode2 = select(num_mod, -sex)

Comment: for some reason it says that there's no select function in R

Comment: you need to load the library, see the start of the code. you can type `require(dplyr)` right before the select statement.

Comment: now i'm getting an error that looks like this:

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `Male`, `Male`, `Male`, `Male`, `Male`, etc. don't exist.